# Struts 1 - Are there any issues with validating in the action class instead of the form?

Tags: java, validation, security, struts-1

There is a struts1 application that I am supporting and I am trying to make it pass a Fortify scan.  In addition to that, I believe that all code in a struts1 application should be in the action class (or Java class called by the action class).  You should not have JDBC code in a JSP or a bean used in a JSP.  Is that correct?

Trying to keep all data access code in the action class and doing input validation in the Struts1 action form creates a problem.  The problem is, if a validation error occurs, the code to prefill fields on an edit screen with the existing values is not executed again.  So, when a validation error happens, all the text boxes go blank.  The user sees the error message that tells them what they did wrong, but all the existing prefilled values are gone.

If you do the validation in the action class instead of the action form (make validate() method in action form empty), then you can get the action class to execute again and keep the prefilled values.  I don't mind doing that as long as there is no consequences of doing so.  My question is, is it ok to do the validation in the action class like this instead of the action form?  Is there any reason why you shouldn't do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> You should not have JDBC code in a JSP or a bean used in a JSP. Is that correct?

JSPs are view-layer only; there certainly "shouldn't" be any JDBC access in a JSP. A bean *used* by the JSP is a completely different animal, especially in S1, where `ActionForm`s are used for multiple concerns.

> Trying to keep all data access code in the action class and doing input validation in the Struts1 action form creates a problem.

It shouldn't; that's what the `ActionForm#validate` is for–validation. If that means doing data access, no S1 convention is being broken (although I'd externalize it to a data access class). If the form fields are being sent back blank that's an issue with the implementation.

In a framework it's best to work within its conventions. You *may* do validation anywhere you want–one reason you *shouldn't* is because it's counter to normal S1 application flow.

Comment: If I do the validation in the ActionForm validation and an action error does occur, how will the form fields be prefilled again?  Before, they were getting prefilled because the JDBC code to get the data to fill them was in the bean being used in the JSP.  If the validate() method returns action errors, no action class is executed to prefill the data again.

Comment: @CharlesCarrington That's an odd pattern--ActionForms should be ready before hitting the view layer. That's what `reset` is for (default values), but it also depends on what the actual request flow is.